# Looping through SQL query in python and saving to csv file by date

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, loops, csv

**Task Description**

Hi

I have a database and want to retrieve everything from it using SQL within python. I am interested in saving specific `date` periods to their own csv file. For example to obtain all of the year 2000, the `date` would be between 20000101 and 20001231 (yyyy-mm-dd). This works perfectly with the below code:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN 20000101 AND 20001231', database)
df.to_csv('2000_data.csv', sep =',')
```

However, I wish to loop through different years, specifically 1960 until 2018, so there will be a total of 58 different csv files output.

I can manually just change the date as follows:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN 20010101 AND 20011231', database)
df.to_csv('2001_data.csv', sep =',')
```

But this is very inefficient. Any ideas for making this a loop with the dates changing in the query part of the code and the year changing when outputting to the respective csv file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sequence of values, stepping ever 10k, and then iterate through the using parameterization.

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?'

for num in range(19600101, 20180102, 10000):
  df = pd.read_sql(sql, database, params=[num, num+1130]) 
  df.to_csv('{}_data.csv'.format(str(num)[:4]))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks heap mate! :)

Comment: One question, what is the +1130 doing ?

Comment: It adds the needed numbers from Jan. 1 to render Dec. 31. See demo: https://rextester.com/CYANP57336